# Replace nulls on empty collections when deserializing objects using google.gson

Tags: java, gson, json-deserialization

I have class like that:

```
class Item
{
    private final List<SubItem> subItems= new LinkedList<SubItem>();
    public List<SubItem> getSubItems() {
        return subItems;
    }
    ...
}
```

I using `google.gson` for serialization/deserialization classes. And when i use this class after deserialization  `subItems` can contains `null`. How i can avoid nulls into `subItems` after deserialization and get empty collection instead them?

Comment: Where did the nulls come from ? I find it hard to believe that gson added arbitrary nulls to your collection during serialization/deserialization.

Comment: if json not contains something like "subItems":[...]  i have null in subItems after deserialization. But i want to have empty collection instead null. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you serialize it with the code example you posted above, the json *will* contain: `"subItems":[]`. You should provide the use-case in the question and provide a way to reproduce the result you're getting (expected output vs. wanted output etc).

Comment: Ok. i will add json example later. Main problem that is REST Api, not serialization/deserialization proccess inside my application. So i cant control proccess of creating json for api clients, but i want simplify working with deserializtion results and avoid "!= null" checking for 'item.SubItems' in my code.